# Why does Lex/flex show input although it isn't matched?

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

```
%%
[0-9]+ {printf("%s is a number\n",yytext);}
%%
int main()
{
   yylex();
}
```

For input `affafe` it results `affafe`, but it is not matched. How can I stop showing unmatched input in output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(F)lex inserts a default action to handle the case where no pattern matches. The default action matches a single character *and echoes it to standard output*.

To avoid that, add your own fallback rule at the end of your patterns which matches a single character and does nothing:

```
.|\n      ;
```